# How to add "document" with addEventListener inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML that is created dynamically. So the `click` event not working on that. To solve this I added `document` before `addEventListener` in my below code like this

```
document.acc[i].addEventListener
```

But it's not working. Can anyone tell how we can add `document` in this code so that event will work perfectly on the dynamically created elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show your HTML. What do you mean by "not working"--is there an error? The code block you show looks generally OK.

Comment: It should be `document.addEventListener()`, not `document.acc[i].addEventListener()`.

Comment: @Barmar "document.addEventListener()" by using this "click event" not working. and we can not skip ".acc[i]". That is my question how I should add document with "acc[i].addEventListener"

Comment: @ggorlen. No error is showing , just my click event not working

Comment: @ggorlen my given code is ok, But when I add "document."  with acc[i].addEventListener then click event stops working

Comment: See the linked question for how to do delegation to dynamically added elements.

Comment: The code you wrote is running when the page is loaded, before the dynamic elements have been added.